# Python - How to know how many kinds of objects there are in a list

Tags: python, types

```
a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
```

I want answer to be 4 since there are 4 types (1,2,3,4)

Is there any module to do this?

Comment: These aren't types in the programming sense.  You're looking for "unique values"

Comment: These are not "types", as understood by Python. You are rather asking a question about unique integers.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you want?

```
In [11]: a=[1,1,2,3,2,4,4,3]

In [12]: c=set(a)

In [13]: len(c)
Out[13]: 4

In [14]: c
Out[14]: set([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `len(set(a))`.  This puts them into a set, which holds only unique items

`a` gets collapsed to `{1,2,3,4}`, which has a length of 4

Comment: Depending on the application, it may make more sense to have `a` just be a set in the first place.

Comment: also, if you want the list back, you can just use a=list(set[a]) which will return [1,2,3,4]

Comment: @erica: Only if you don't care about order. If you care about order, Manoj Pandey's answer would be more appropriate.

Comment: @user2760368 could you clickety-clack that check mark under/next to the answer score?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the duplicates using the following. Note that with set, you do not have a defined order.

```
>>> a = [1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4]
>>> print list(set(a))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: using the fact of dict key uniqueness is pretty useless, since it does not have any advantage over set approach, but has some drawbacks (such as need to import another module, discarding of values, and even longer code). Set approach you have taken is better, except you misunderstood the question (it was about finding a number, not list).

Comment: @Tadeck, thnx! In that case, the OP can simply count hte number of element in the set: len(set(a)).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use len(set(list)) as mentioned above, another way of doing this, although more roundabout; is with a for loop:

```
listA = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
listB = []
for x in listA:
    if x not in listB:
        listB.append(x)
print listB
```

This way you have your original list, and a new one that you can do whatever you want without worrying about affecting the original list.